# 'System cannot find the specified file path' error - BlueJ

Tags: java, file, input, java.util.scanner

I'm creating a Quiz program in BlueJ where I read in my questions.csv file and then break them up into an array of objects.

My Question file is located in the same directory as both my package file, and my .class files.
I have already tried specifiying the absolute path file (C://Users ...), and also tried using the .getAbsoluteFilePath() method. None have worked.

If anyone has any solutions as to how I can read in the file successfully, that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

[Here is a screenshot of my project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pPOs.png)

**Here is the section of my code which reads in the file**

````
       String csv = "";
       String[] valueList = new String[4];
    
       // identify file
       String inputFile = ("questions.csv");
       // open file
       Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
    
       // loop for every csv row, fetch from file and store
       for (int i = 0; i < questionList.length; i++) {
    
         csv = fileReader.nextLine();
         valueList = csv.split(",");
    
         // new instance of the Question class (record)
         questionList[i] = new Question(valueList[0], valueList[1], valueList[2], valueList[3], valueList[4]);
       }
    
       fileReader.close();
    } // end readQuestionFile()```
````

Comment: It's the basic OS. Nothing to do with JAVA. The way you coded refers to the CURRENT WORKING directory.

Comment: Hi Joe, I'm aware of this but even if I program in the absolute path, it still doesn't respond properly. Thanks.